# PHP Session problem. When item is added it adds 1 to all of the items

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I am making a shopping cart where when you click on either of two cars you add that item to the shopping cart. The problem is that when I click for example on the BMW picture the count goes up for both BMW and Toyota. I've been struggling on this for over 2 days now and I can't figure it out!

Here is my first page. When I click on either of pictures I want it to add it to the shopping cart. I want to use session to work this out.

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php include('navbar.php');?>

    <h1>OstosKoriTori</h1>
    <h3>Click the picture to add the car to your shopping cart!</h3>
    <p>Toyota Chaser JZX 100</p>
    <p>BMW E92</p>
    <div class="autot">

    <a href="add-basket.php?id=chaser"><img src="chaser.jpg" alt="Chaseri"></a>
    <a href="add-basket.php?id=bmw"><img src="bmw.jpg" alt="Bemari"></a>
    <br>
    </div>
```

Here is the second page, this code is run when you select the picture. **I believe the problem is here.**

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['chaser'])){
    $_SESSION['chaser'] = 0;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['chaser'])){
    $_SESSION['chaser'] += 1;
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['bmw'])){
    $_SESSION['bmw'] = 0;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['bmw'])){
    $_SESSION['bmw'] += 1;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/'
    . "basket-session.php"); 
    ?>
```

And here is the last page where you can see how many cars you have depending on how many times you clicked on the picture.

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php include('navbar.php')?>
    <h1>OstosKoriTori</h1>
    <h3>Ostoskorin sisältö</h3>
    <p>Toyota Chaser JZX 100</p>
    <p>BMW E92</p>
    <div class="kuvat">
    <img src="chaser.jpg" alt="Chaseri">
    <img src="bmw.jpg" alt="Bemari">
    </div>
    <div class="kpl">
    <p><?php echo "Korissa on: <strong>" . $_SESSION['chaser'] . "</strong> kpl"; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo "Korissa on: <strong>" . $_SESSION['bmw'] . "</strong> kpl"; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBasket">
    <a href="clear-basket.php">Tyhjennä ostoskori</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay, so immediately the problem is clear. The first time you load the page, the session is empty, so values for `chaser` and `bmw` are initialised to 0. The next time the code is run, `isset()` will return true for both `chaser` and `bmw`, because although the value is `0`, it is set, hence both values are incremented by `1`.

Comment: How can I fix this problem? I'm sorry I didn't quite understood. Shouldn't I use isset()?

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted, something like this should work. I've added some comments to explain the code.

```
<?php 

session_start();

// Initialise session to existing value or zero
$_SESSION['chaser'] = $_SESSION['chaser'] ?? 0;
$_SESSION['bmw'] = $_SESSION['bmw'] ?? 0;

// Determine selected car
$car = $_GET['id'] ?? null;

// Increment selected car
if ($car) {
    $_SESSION[$car] += 1;
}

header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/basket-session.php');
```

Comment: Oh, wow that worked! Thank you so much! I have a question about $_GET['id'] part. Does it automatically choose the right id when the corresponding picture is clicked? I didn't know that you can do that. Thank you once again!

Comment: When you click the link, you'll notice that the browser URL changes and includes the `id` parameter. This is called a query string parameter, for which the value can be accessed through the superglobal variable `$_GET`. So yes, whichever link you click, the parameter will contain the corresponding value.

Comment: Okay that explains a lot! Thank you!